# Subsetting data in Python

Tags: python, arrays, r, numpy, subset

I want to use the equivalent of the subset command in R for some Python code I am writing.

Here is my data:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
100002  2006    1.1 0.01    6352
100002  2006    1.2 0.84    304518
100002  2006    2   1.52    148219
100002  2007    1.1 0.01    6292
10002   2006    1.1 0.01    5968
10002   2006    1.2 0.25    104318
10002   2007    1.1 0.01    6800
10002   2007    4   2.03    25446
10002   2008    1.1 0.01    6408
```

I want to subset the data based on contents of `col1` and `col2`. (The unique values in col1 are 100002 and 10002, and in col2 are 2006,2007 and 2008.)

This can be done in R using the subset command, is there anything similar in Python?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

While the iterator-based answers are perfectly fine, if you're working with numpy arrays (as you mention that you are) there are better and faster ways of selecting things:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([
        [100002, 2006, 1.1, 0.01, 6352],
        [100002, 2006, 1.2, 0.84, 304518],
        [100002, 2006, 2,   1.52, 148219],
        [100002, 2007, 1.1, 0.01, 6292],
        [10002,  2006, 1.1, 0.01, 5968],
        [10002,  2006, 1.2, 0.25, 104318],
        [10002,  2007, 1.1, 0.01, 6800],
        [10002,  2007, 4,   2.03, 25446],
        [10002,  2008, 1.1, 0.01, 6408]    ])

subset1 = data[data[:,0] == 100002]
subset2 = data[data[:,0] == 10002]
```

This yields

subset1:

```
array([[  1.00002e+05,   2.006e+03,   1.10e+00, 1.00e-02,   6.352e+03],
       [  1.00002e+05,   2.006e+03,   1.20e+00, 8.40e-01,   3.04518e+05],
       [  1.00002e+05,   2.006e+03,   2.00e+00, 1.52e+00,   1.48219e+05],
       [  1.00002e+05,   2.007e+03,   1.10e+00, 1.00e-02,   6.292e+03]])
```

subset2:

```
array([[  1.0002e+04,   2.006e+03,   1.10e+00, 1.00e-02,   5.968e+03],
       [  1.0002e+04,   2.006e+03,   1.20e+00, 2.50e-01,   1.04318e+05],
       [  1.0002e+04,   2.007e+03,   1.10e+00, 1.00e-02,   6.800e+03],
       [  1.0002e+04,   2.007e+03,   4.00e+00, 2.03e+00,   2.5446e+04],
       [  1.0002e+04,   2.008e+03,   1.10e+00, 1.00e-02,   6.408e+03]])
```

If you didn't know the unique values in the first column beforehand, you can use either [`numpy.unique1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.3.x/reference/generated/numpy.unique1d.html) or the builtin function `set` to find them.

Edit: I just realized that you wanted to select data where you have unique combinations of two columns... In that case, you might do something like this:

```
col1 = data[:,0]
col2 = data[:,1]

subsets = {}
for val1, val2 in itertools.product(np.unique(col1), np.unique(col2)):
    subset = data[(col1 == val1) & (col2 == val2)]
    if np.any(subset):
        subsets[(val1, val2)] = subset
```

(I'm storing the subsets as a dict, with the key being a tuple of the combination... There are certainly other (and better, depending on what you're doing) ways to do this!)

Comment: Thanks! In retrospect this is so obvious that I should have tried it myself, but your explanation is very complete. However, do you know how much of a speed up we can obtain using this approach compared to iterators? I thought that iterators are pretty fast too!

Comment: @user308827 - They are, but if you're working with numpy arrays, and not lists, using the numpy way of doing things will be faster.  Generally speaking, iterating through an entire numpy array is slow. Iterator-based solutions have to iterate through each element in python.  When you select a subset of a numpy array using a boolean numpy array, the iteration is done behind the scenes in compiled code.  (I'm oversimplifying here, but that's the gist, anyway).  Basically, if you're using numpy arrays to contain your data, it's faster to operate on them with numpy functions.

Comment: Also, is there a way to combine 2 conditions in the subset? E.g., subset1 = data[(data[:,0] == 100002) and (data[:,1] == 2007)] does not seem to work. thanks!

Comment: See my most recent edit... With numpy arrays, you have to use `&` instead of `and` for boolean logic. (It's one of the more common gotcha's...)

Answer (score 5):

`subset()` in R is pretty much analogous to `filter()` in Python.  As the reference notes, this will be used implicitly by list comprehensions, so the most concise and clear way to write the code might be

```
[ item for item in items if item.col2 == 2006 ]
```

if, for example, your data rows were in an iterable called `items`.

Answer (score 2):

Since I'm not familiar with R nor how this subset command works based upon your description I can suggest you take a look at itertool's groupby functionality.  If given a function which outputs a value, you can form groups based upon that function's output.  Taken from [groupby](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
groups = []
uniquekeys = []
data = sorted(data, key=keyfunc)
for k, g in groupby(data, keyfunc):
    groups.append(list(g))      # Store group iterator as a list
    uniquekeys.append(k)
```

and then you've got your subsets.  However, do be careful as the values returned are not full fledged lists.  They're iterators.

I am assuming that your values are being returned on a row-by-row basis.