# Subsetting numpy array by hour and day of week

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, conditional-statements, subset

I have a numpy array containing millions of hourly x y points with the "columns" of the array being x, y, hour, and day of week (all ints). Here is an example of what the array looks like:

```
array([[1, 2, 0, 0],
       [3, 5, 0, 0],
       [6, 3, 1, 0],
       [6, 2, 3, 0],
       [4, 3, 3, 1]])
```

I have created a grid of zeros that I can increment for all values in the array:

```
grid = np.zeros((8,8))
for value in range(0,len(xy_new[:,1])):  
    grid[xy_new[value][1],xy_new[value][0]] += 1
```

but I need to be able to do this for each hour by day of week (ie Sun at hour 0, Sun at hour 1, etc.).

How do I subset the array by hour and day of week?

I have attempted modifying the answers here: [Make subset of array, based on values of two other arrays in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23109366/make-subset-of-array-based-on-values-of-two-other-arrays-in-python), [Subsetting data in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806878/subsetting-data-in-python), but have not been successful. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: and what's the question?

Comment: How do I subset the array by day and hour to count the number of times each point is accessed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you want to wind up with 24 times 7 or 168 sets of accumulated counts for pairs of `x` and `y`.  Suppose you have your data in a `N` by 4 array `gdat`.  First, make week-hour index:

```
whr = 24*gdat[:,2] + gdat[:,3]
```

You can now select the `gdat` rows for each hour in your week.  For example, for hour zero of Sunday:

```
gdat0 = gdat[whr == 0]
```

Do whatever summing you need with `gdat0` and move on to the next hour.

Note that `unique` is probably a faster way to count occurrences of `x, y` pairs.  You can play the same game of making a composite index for `x` and `y`, but you have to know how they are bounded.  Supposing `x` runs from 0 to 120 and `y` runs from 0 to 5, you could make a composite index using bit fields:

```
xy = (gdat0[:,0] << 3) & (gdat0[:,1])
```

Obviously, if `y` has a larger range you need to shift more than 3 bits, and you may need to offset `x` and `y` to avoid negative values.

Then, use `unique` to return the unique values and counts for the values in `xy`.

```
xyval, xycnt = np.unique(xy, return_counts=True)
```

You then retrieve the `x` and `y` value pairs from `xyval` using bitwise operators, `xyval >> 3` and `xyval & 7`.

Repeat for every hour in the week.  Since storage will be an issue if `N` is huge, you probably want to re-use `gdat0` on each iteration.

*EDIT:* The short data sample you posted is time-sequential.  If all your data are time-sequential, you don't need to "select" for each hour.  All you need is to find the index for each new value in `whr`.  `unique(whr, return_index=True)` will find those for you as well!

Comment: Thank you! The first method you provided worked quite well once I changed gdat0 = gdat[:, whr == 0] to gdat0 = gdat[whr == 0]. The way you had it created an error: index out of range in dimension 1